# Is there a chrome API that gives me the status code of the website

Tags: api, google-chrome-extension

If I go to the website, it either gives me the website or "This site cannot be reached". I wanna know the same thing in my chrome extension whether the site can be reached or not. How do I do this. Is there a chrome API I can use for the aforesaid task.

Comment: There's no direct solution but you can probably use chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred event listener. To check the URL status you can also use the standard `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` with `HEAD` method.

Comment: fetch or xmlhttprequest request would give me CORS error...so could not do that for some websites.

Comment: You need to make the request in the background script and add the URL into `"permissions"` as described in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr).

Comment: Thanks, did it using the xhr way but could not do it with the onErrorOccured way. Lets say on the click of the extension, the extension refreshes the page if there is an error; How do I do this with the webnavigation method.

Comment: i cannot say where the error happened, so sorry for asking the whole code.

Comment: webNavigation should be used in the background script, and it needs a permission in manifest.json, see [examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:webnavigation).

Comment: did that ... not working

Comment: I can't help without seeing the code and [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping....At last finished it. Works perfectly fine. Again Thanks.